# Implementing close and reopen mechanism for posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a close-and-reopen mechanism like SO.

**Here is my current algorithm:** I have a table like this:

```
// close_posts
+----+---------+---------+
| id | post_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Also I have a column into `posts` table named `closed` `(tinyint default 0)` which will be increased *after insert* into `close_posts` table via a trigger.

Also I have a condition like this:

```
if ( $post['closed'] >= 5 ){
    echo "the post is closed"
}
```

Which determines the post is closed.

---

Now I want to know how can I also add **reopen** mechanism to it?

- Do I need another table named something like `open_posts` which should decrease `closed` column (in `posts` table)? (in this case that `if`-statement won't work anymore)
- Do I need to modify `close-posts` table and add some columns to specify the type of the either close or reopen vote?

Or any better idea?

Comment: Why do you have different table for ```closed posts```? There should be 2 master table ```User``` and ```Post```. One column(```status```) in ```Post``` table to define if post is opened or closed. Both open and closed posts could be stored in same table

Comment: What's the idea behind the separate `open_posts` and `closed_posts` tables? Are that some kind of votes, i.e. in `open_posts` the votes for closing the post are stored an analog for `closed_posts`?